# AFNetworking cocoapods build fails for WatchOS 2 extension

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods, watchkit

I'm trying to build a Swift WatchKit app for WatchOS 2 with Xcode 7.0, using Cocoapods and including AFNetworking which, I gather, supports watchOS2 from version 2.6.0...

I've reverted all the way back to an empty project which just includes a watch extension target and tries to import AFNetworking:

[image]

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

workspace 'AFNetworkingTest.xcworkspace'

target "WatchApp Extension" do
use_frameworks!
platform :watchos, '2.0'
pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

Configure cocoapods:

```
$ pod --version
0.38.2

$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 0.39.0.beta.4 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.6.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
```

ExtensionDelegate.swift:

```
import WatchKit
import AFNetworking

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

}
```

Build fails in Pods > AFNetworking > AFNetworking.h, with error:

> **AFURLSessionManager.h file not found**

[image]

Looking at the generated Pods project, it seems that the AFNetworking pod only includes a handful of files (and, as reported, is missing AFURLSessionManager, along with what looks like a lot of other files):

[image]

Am I missing something here?

- Is this a bug in the pod or am I missing something in the Podfile?
- Have I missed something in the build settings? (I'm hitting the same problem in an existing project, so tried a brand new project with the default build settings, and got the same error).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the podspec (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4208)

The easiest fix for this would be to use the repo directly until 2.6.1 podspec is pushed.

`pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git', branch: 'master'`

Answer (score 0):

From what I've managed to figure out, it looks like this is a bug in the 2.6.0 pod spec.

I was able to fix the build issue by updating **~/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/AFNetworking/2.6.0/AFNetworking.podspec.json**,  adding "watchos" to the list of platforms under NSURLSession, i.e:

```
...
{
  "name": "NSURLSession",
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "7.0",
    "osx": "10.9",
    "watchos": "2.0"
  },
...
```

Running pod install again fixed the issue.

I can see the same [commit](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/a44c8a4d0f75a54acfa3dc378c881166fc91cde8) was made to the AFNetworking source code a month ago, so hopefully the pod will be updated to a new version soon.